# The meaning of "lawful cuts of a ground-ash"

Tags: meaning

> Ten years at an English public school do not encourage dreaming. Georgie won his growth and chest measurement, and a few other things which did not appear in the bills, under a system of cricket, football, and paper-chases, from four to five days a week, which provided for three **lawful cuts of a ground-ash** if any boy absented himself from these entertainments.

This is from "The Brushwood Boy" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-brushwood-boy.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
lawful cuts of a ground-ash

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: It refers to corporal punishment, which for many decades now has been unlawful in Britain, as it is in most civilised countries.

Answer (score 3):

Ash is a tree known for producing very strong and straight wood. A "[ground ash](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ground%20ash)" is a walking stick made from an ash sapling. This stick won't break when you hit someone over the back with it.

Here, a "cut" means a hit or blow.

So the phrase, means "three hits with a very hard stick".

"Lawful" has its normal meaning.

Comment: thank you very much for your clear and precise answer. It is so helpful!